# Flashcards class installed incompletely on MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, flashcards

I don't have much experience with low-level LaTeX. MiKTeX (my version is `basic-miktex-2.9.3972`) always installed needed packages "on-the-fly".

Trying to compile a document using `1.0.1` version of `flashcards` package (available at [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/)), I encountered the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...@onefilewithoptions #1[{\cardpaper 
                                                  }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
```

That led me to inspect the `flashcards.cls` file in `tex/latex/Flashcards`, and notice `\cardpaper` option in not defined in that document.
After that, I manually downloaded `flashcards.dtx` file from ctan and compiled it twice, to produce configuration files `avery5371.cfg` and `avery5388.cfg`, as well as the documentation file.

When the configuration files are present with my source file, the document compiles without problems

My question:
Is this "normal" behaviour (expecting that I should compile required parts of the package manually)?

Comment: A better title would be "Flashcards class installed incompletely on MiKTeX". Apparently the *class* (`.cls`) is installed, otherwise you would get a different error. Also please do net refer to `.cls` or `.sty` files as *documents*, because that's confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your useful advice. English is not my first language, but I should be more careful. The `flashcards` package version is 1.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not expected to compile required parts manually.

This seems to be an mistake with the MikTeX package of `flashcards`. The `.cfg` files were simply not included (I checked the MikTeX archive file on CTAN). You should contact the MikTeX team and tell them about the missing files.

For future questions: Please post not only the version number of MikTeX but the version(s) of the used package(s). Both are independent. At best you update all packages beforehand.