# Flashcard Compilation Error

Tags: packages, miktex, compiling, installing, flashcards

I apologize if this has already been answered somewhere. I've been trying to make flashcards in MikTeX, and I've installed the package. Here is my sample code.

```
\documentclass[frame]{flashcards}
\begin{document}
\begin{flascard}{why}
are you doing this to me
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

And this is the error I get when I compile using TeXWorks and WinEdt:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Latex/testing 3.tex"
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\flashcards\flashcards.cls"
Document Class: flashcards 2010/08/13 1.0.1 (matthew@debian.org)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...@onefilewithoptions #1[{\cardpaper 
                                              }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
l.77 \setlength
           {\oddevenshift}{\oddoffset}
?
```

More specifically, when I click on the warnings and errors tab in TeXWorks, it displays this:

```
flashcards.cls
77
Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...@onefilewithoptions #1[{\cardpaper 
                                              }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
l.77 \setlength
           {\oddevenshift}{\oddoffset}
```

I've been racking my brain with this since 10a.m. this morning. The things I have tried include uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting my computer, downloading the flashcards folder and putting it in the tex file (which I honestly don't know if I put it in the right folder or not), uninstalling MikTeX 2.9 and reinstalling the newest version. Sometime before, when I didn't manaully install the package, it gave me the error telling me that flashcards.cls not found. I'm so confused, and after reading the pdf, it seems like the perfect set up for me to make some flashcards...can anyone please help me by telling me what that error means and how to fix it? It will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I had a typo in the code above. This is the one that I compiled more recently after correction (thanks to Willie Wong):

```
\documentclass[frame,avery5388]{flashcards}
\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{why}
are you doing this to me
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

and here is the error that it produced:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Jay/Documents/untitled-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\flashcards\flashcards.cls"
Document Class: flashcards 2010/08/13 1.0.1 (matthew@debian.org)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
Coudln't find avery5388.cfg, using defualt.
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...@onefilewithoptions #1[{\cardpaper 
                                              }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
l.77 \setlength
           {\oddevenshift}{\oddoffset}
?
```

Evidently, the `avery5388.cfg` file isn't being read. Anyone have any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: The flashcards documentation states "All documents should specify the paper type." You did not specify the paper type. Try passing `avery5388` as an option in `\documentclass[frame,avery5388]{flashcards}`.

Comment: You _don't_ compile the `.cls` file. That bottom part of your question is entirely unhelpful. You said that you tried with the option: please edit your question to reflect the exact file that you used. Because if I include the `avery5388` option and fix the typo in `\begin{flascard}`, the file compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: For MikTeX users, apparently there is a bug in the packaging of the `flashcards` package, resulting in certain crucial configuration files being left out. A quick workaround is to copy the following code:

```
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{3}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{1}
\setlength{\cardheight}{3.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{5.0in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{1.0in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{1.75in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{1.75in}
```

paste it into a file called `avery5388.cfg`, and put the file in the same directory as your tex file.

**Alternatively**, instead of creating `avery5388.cfg` by hand, you can do it using TeX's `filecontents` command. To do this, just edit your tex source code as

```
\begin{filecontents}{avery5388.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{3}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{1}
\setlength{\cardheight}{3.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{5.0in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{1.0in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{1.75in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{1.75in}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[frame,avery5388]{flashcards}
\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{why}
are you doing this to me
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above code should, in principle, create automatically the necessary `.cfg` file if it doesn't exist already.

---

Per the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards?lang=en), it is imperative to specify a paper size when using the `flashcards` document class. The class pre-defines two sizes, one of which is `avery5388` for use with index cards (the other is for use with business-card sized cards). The manual has complete instructions on how to define custom sized cards.

Your error message indicates that the command sequence

```
\cardpaper
```

is not defined. This is exactly what would happen if you did not define a paper size (reading through the `.cls` file code). (It is a bit funny that there is no default defined, but whatever.)

So fixing your code to read

```
\documentclass[frame,avery5388]{flashcards}
\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{why}
are you doing this to me
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

it builds just fine

```
[Fri Jul 29 10:12 AM] ArchDesktop ~/tmp $ pdflatex t.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./t.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/flashcards/flashcards.cls
Document Class: flashcards 2010/08/13 1.0.1 (matthew@debian.org)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/flashcards/avery5388.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))) (./t.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./t.aux) )</usr/sha
re/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on t.pdf (2 pages, 21254 bytes).
Transcript written on t.log.
```

with output (2 pages, somewhat unevenly cropped in my image viewer)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I copied your code, and it generated the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, it seems like someone else was having a problem like this, but I don't understand any of what they did...(http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11408/flashcards-class-installed-incompletely-on-miktex), maybe this will help out? I appreciate your time thus far.

Comment: @kingdras: basically MikTeX didn't include a working version of the flashcards document class. And apparently they still haven't fixed it since 5 years ago. I'll edit with a workaround.

Comment: @kingdras: incidentally, you really should've copied and pasted the full logs (as you have done in the question for the version without the `avery5388` option) after you still saw the error when you tried it with the option. The error is in fact subtly different: with the `avery5388` option specified, a few lines above the `Undefined control sequence` you should've seen also the line `Couldn't find avery5388.cfg, using default.` which would've helped narrowing down the problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry...something came up and had my brain all fuzzed out, I'm good now. I just realized right before you commented that I did get the error `Couldn't find avery5388.cfg`. I apologize, my struggle with code, and lack of experience with TeX stack exchange makes my communication horrible ._.

Comment: @kingdras: no worries! My comment, if sounded accusatory, is not meant to be. I understand you are a new member to our community and was just trying to give helpful advice for the next time you ask a question!

Comment: OK, above you said copy the code and paste it to a file titled `avery5388.cfg`. Do I copy the code, paste it on a notepad, and then title it `avery5388.cfg`, or am I looking for that file? Also, this is a really dumb question, how exactly do I find my tex file?

Comment: @kingdras: To answer the first part of you comment: yes. For the second part, you can use Windows's search facility...  Give me 5 minutes and I can include an alternate method in the answer which may or may not be easier.