# How to adapt the avery5371 flashcards to fit 4 on 1 page instead of 10 on 1 page?

Tags: flashcards

```
\documentclass[avery5371,grid]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\cardfrontfoot{Behavioral Finance} % footer in bottom right

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{datetime}

% Custom colours 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\providecommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\providecommand{\gray}[1]{{\color{gray} #1}}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flashcard}
[
    Lecture 3
]
{
    What was week 1-2 about
}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{center}
    Deviations from the standard assumptions at the level of the individual.
    Nonstandard preferences and nonstandard belief. 
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

I really enjoy the avery5371 LaTeX flashcards but they come in 10 on 1 page. When I print these out and cut these out these are too small for me. Is there any way for me to turn these into 4 on 1 page flashcards (in landscape mode) instead of 10 on 1 page flashcards?

Comment: The `flashcard` package provides out of the box the `avery5388` option which gives bigger (3 per page) cards. See [section 4 of the documentation](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/flashcards.pdf) to define your own geometry.

Comment: BTW, MikTeX users should note https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11408/flashcards-class-installed-incompletely-on-miktex